# What is preferable: an Enum or a singleton

Tags: c#, enums, singleton

I have the folowing question:

What is the prefered way to use the status in code, an enum OR singleton?

I have in a DB stored the status values with their ID's. If the status changes in de DB is would also need some changes in the code.

does anyone now what is more prefered, based on conventions?

I've been looking on the internet but couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: What's "an enum of a singleton"?

Comment: not sure i understand the question. what is "enum of a singleton"? If you mean "enum OR a singleton", still doesn't make sense. enum is a value type used to defined a named set of constants. singleton is a pattern where you define one instance of something to be used by your entire application.

Comment: it's about my statusses are stored in a DB, i could make an Enum class with the same values, or retrieve the values from the DB with the singleton and make them available.

Comment: How can i change the question from "What is more prefered an Enum of a singleton" to "What is more prefered an Enum OR a singleton", 

[edit]
thanks for changing the title

Comment: okay, that makes a lot more sense that your original question. how often are the values likely to change? if not at all, use constants. if they are to change regularly, then fetch them from the db and "cache" them somewhere until they change. i say cache with quotes because you haven't said what type of application this is (web/windows/silverlight, etc)

Comment: It's a Webservice that wil be contacted from SharePoint Webparts.

Comment: and how often do these statuses change, and what triggers the change? and what type of web service - ASMX or WCF? SOAP or REST?

Comment: it would possible never change or maybe once or twice. The cause of changes would be a workflow step.  Webservice is WCF

Comment: Yep, cool. Then grab it from the db, cache it no expiry - ie manual eviction. Evict/refresh it when the workflow step comes in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends in part on whether the ids for your statuses have guaranteed values, or whether the ids could change per-database (via an `IDENTITY`). Personally, for statuses I prefer fixed - which gives you the most flexibility, and least overhead - you can choose to use an enum (or maybe some consts if more convenient), and you never have to add an indirection, i.e. "get the id that is `open`".

This isn't always possible, though, and when it *isn't* it is still definitely useful to cache and re-use them (to avoid hitting the DB for that lookup). However, I would avoid a singleton, not least because it won't play nicely if you ever need to talk to more than one database - the ids in each could well be different. However, any suitable cache implementation (or maybe IoC/DI) should allow you to store the appropriate data (probably some kind of dictionary). Singletons are also just a bit of a pain *generally* if you like testing etc.

But: an enum and fixed id values is a lot simpler.

Note that under *any* implementation, changing the status list is a non-trivial operation, not least it will be a big `UPDATE` (or several if you are denormalized).

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to use the Status across the application and is standardised across then it would be best fit for an `Enum`

```
Enum Status
{Open, Pending, Closed, Deferred}
```

Also this makes the code more *readable*